# Firebase Messaging requestPermission Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a simple function to request Permission for Firebase Messaging

```
Future requestPermissionFCM() async {
  final FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission();
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permision');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    print('User granted provisional permission');
  } else {
    print('user declined or has not accepted permission');
  }
}
```

I call in during initState in main.dart
and exactly this line

```
final NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission();
```

causes the Unhandled Exception

```
E/flutter (11771): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
E/flutter (11771): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (11771): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter (11771): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11771): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:518:43)
E/flutter (11771): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11771): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.requestPermission (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:271:36)
E/flutter (11771): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11771): #4      requestPermissionFCM (package:dev/services/fcm_services.dart:30:41)
E/flutter (11771): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Despite this exception, the app does not crush and messaging works as it should be including background push notifications. So what can it be?